# Allow systemd static IP edit in read-only Yocto file system

Tags: systemd, symlink, yocto

I have a custom recipe that copy a systemd .network configuration file in /etc/systemd/network, setting a static IP to my system.

Since many devices can be connected to the same network, I'd like the user to be able to edit the system IP address.

My image have a read-only root partition, and a writeable home partition. My idea was to have the .network file in /etc/systemd/network be a link to a file in home, so that the user can edit it (via a remote software that won't screw up the file, obviously).

```
# ll /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep 16 15:16 /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network -> /home/root/systemd/20-wired.network*
```

These are the permission for the linked file

```
# ll /home/root/systemd/20-wired.network
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 107 Mar  9  2018 /home/root/systemd/20-wired.network*
```

Awfully, the link trick doesn't work:

```
# systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
* systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-09-16 15:19:31 UTC; 6min ago
TriggeredBy: * systemd-networkd.socket
             Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
     Main PID: 413 (systemd-network)
         Status: "Processing requests..."
            Tasks: 1 (limit: 520)
         Memory: 2.0M
         CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
                         `-413 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Sep 16 15:19:31 imx8mpsolidrun systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Sep 16 15:19:31 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: Failed to load /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network, ignoring: Permission denied
Sep 16 15:19:31 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: Enumeration completed
Sep 16 15:19:31 imx8mpsolidrun systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Sep 16 15:19:31 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: eth0: Link UP
Sep 16 15:19:36 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: eth0: Gained carrier
Sep 16 15:19:37 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 10.0.10.240/24 via 10.0.10.1
Sep 16 15:19:37 imx8mpsolidrun systemd-networkd[413]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
```

If the linked file is in the root partition instead of the home one, the link trick works. But then it will be read-only again...

I think it is due to the fact that the systemd-networkd service have `ProtectHome=yes`. I tried disabling this feature, by setting it to `no`, `false` and commenting it, but no luck so far. I've also tried setting it to `read-only` and set `ReadOnlyPaths=path/to/linked/file`, but still no luck.

Any idea how to get it to work?

Any better approach to have an editable static IP when the root partition is read-only?

**EDIT**

I made further test, and it looks like it is in fact a file permission access problem.

I confirm that `ProtectHome=no` is needed in `systemd-networkd.service` file, otherwise files in home directories can't be accessed by the service.

What I noticed is that files in any user's home (e.g. `/home/weston/`) can be accessed and used by systemd, but files in `/home/root` can't be accessed, regarding permission set for the whole folder. I tried setting 0777 for all `/home/root/` folder and subfolders, but still the files can't be accessed by systemd. Indeed, `systemd-network` user don't have access to the configuration file.

Here the files permissions (both files seems readable to anyone) and `test` results:

```
# namei -l /home/root/20-wired.network 
f: /home/root/20-wired.network
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr--r-- root root root
-rw-r--r-- root root 20-wired.network
# sudo -u systemd-network test -r /home/root/20-wired.network; echo $?
1
# namei -l /home/weston/20-wired.network 
f: /home/weston/20-wired.network
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwxr-xr-x weston weston weston
-rw-r--r-- weston weston 20-wired.network
# sudo -u systemd-network test -r /home/weston/20-wired.network; echo $?
0
```

I suppose I need better to study `root` access permissions...

Comment: A more general alternative is to use [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html) to mount a RW directory on top of `/etc` (for example) to hold changes. Yocto does support overlayfs. Eg [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171191/5008284) is to have a RW passwd file.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could be useful for some other things, too. Need to do some test.